# Printing out xml nodes in python

Tags: python, html, xml, minidom

I am having trouble getting my xml to print out in python. I am unsure as to how to get the correct nodes to be read. When i run what I currently have nothing prints out at all. I get no errors, just nothing printing.

xml script

```
    <NEWS>
       <ARTICLE>
          <TITLE>Mark Mulder ends 2015 comeback bid</TITLE>
          <AUTHOR>Igor</AUTHOR>
          <PUBLIC>T</PUBLIC>
          <CONTENT>
            38-year-old left-hander Mark Mulder will not be attempting another comeback this tear, according to Jerry Crasnick of ESPN and Baseball America. Mulder tried to return from a lengthy hiatus last year, but a comeback bid ended with a spring training injury in Angels camp last year. "I just couldn't get where I needed to be," Mulder said. Mulder went 103-60 with a 4.18 ERA in nine years in the majors. He hasn't pitched in an MLB game since 2008.
          </CONTENT>
       </ARTICLE>
   <NEWS>
```

python code:

```
 import xml.dom.minidom as minidom
 document = minidom.parse("cgi-bin/news.xml")
     page = document.childNodes[0]

     print "<html>"
     print "<head><title>NEW News Articles List</title></head>"
     print "<body>"
     print "<h2>Welcome to New News Inc.!<br> You are currently a GUEST here.</h2>"
     print """\
     <form method="GET" >
         <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="loginPageCall" >
     </form>
     """

     for child in page.childNodes:
         if child.nodeType == minidom.Node.TEXT_NODE:
             sys.stdout.write(child.data)
         elif child.nodeType == minidom.Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
             if child.nodeName == "TITLE":
                 sys.stdout.write('<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (child.getAttribute("url"), child.childNodes[0].data))
```

Answer (score 0):

**I wonder why you  have extra tab in all the codes.**

```
 import xml.dom.minidom as minidom
 document = minidom.parse("cgi-bin/news.xml")
 page = document.childNodes[0]

 print "<html>"
 print "<head><title>NEW News Articles List</title></head>"
 print "<body>"
 print "<h2>Welcome to New News Inc.!<br> You are currently a GUEST here.</h2>"
 print """\
     <form method="GET" >
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="loginPageCall" >
     </form>
     """

 for child in page.childNodes:
     if child.nodeType == minidom.Node.TEXT_NODE:
         sys.stdout.write(child.data)
     elif child.nodeType == minidom.Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
         if child.nodeName == "TITLE":
             sys.stdout.write('<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (child.getAttribute("url"), child.childNodes[0].data))
```

I haven't even read your code and I am sure that this will at least give you some errors if the logic is wrong.

**Indenting the code will help in this case**